# Using round robin partition assignment strategy giving CommitFailedException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using Spring Boot with Spring kafka
This is my consumer configuration.

```
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> getConsumerProps() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, RoundRobinAssignor.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "300000");
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
        props, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer());
  }
```

I am using the Round Robin partition assignment strategy with manual commit. But whenever I call

```
acknowledgement.acknowledge()
```

I am getting this exception

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to show much more information, logs, etc., before the exception.

Comment: This is the message "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records."

Comment: I never got these exceptions when I didn't use RoundRobin. Why does this happen with RoundRobin?  Is there a permanent solution to this problem?

Comment: That doesn’t make any sense. Partition assignment strategy  should have no bearing on how long your consumer takes to process the records returned by the poll. Why don’t you follow the guidance in the error message.

Comment: So, you are saying that this is not an issue of RoundRobin strategy? Okay, great. Will increase the max poll interval ms then. Thanks.

Comment: Also, the default is 3,00,000ms which is 5 mins. But the code hardly takes few seconds. I don't know why this should be increased?

Comment: Well, clearly it is not if a rebalance is occurring. Refer to my first comment. Nobody can help you without much more information. Even better, provide a complete, minimal, example app that exhibits the behavior.